# CSS transform skew inside MS CRM 2011 web resource

Tags: css, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I am trying to develop a dynamic chevron style progress indicator in a web resource.

Here is a jsfiddle of what I am trying to achieve http://jsfiddle.net/3qYyV/

My problem is that when this is put into a web resource the "transform skew's" do not get applied???

Here is an example web resource...

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">

        .chevron {
            float: left;
            padding: 0px 0px 0px 2px;
            width: 150px;
        }

        .chevron_a {
            height: 100px;
            width: 150px;
            -webkit-transform: skew(20deg, 0deg);
            -moz-transform: skew(20deg, 0deg);
            -ms-transform: skew(20deg, 0deg);
            -o-transform: skew(20deg, 0deg);
            transform: skew(20deg, 0deg);
            float: left;
            z-index: -1;
        }

        .chevron_b {
            height: 100px;
            width: 150px;
            -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg);
            -moz-transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg);
            -ms-transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg);
            -o-transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg);
            transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg);
            float: left;
            z-index: -1;
        }

        .chevron_c {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width: 150px;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Tahoma;
        }

        .chevron_m {
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        .chevron_o{
            clear: both;
            display: table;
            position: absolute;
            width: 150px;
            height: 100px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chevron_w">
        <div class="chevron">
            <div class="chevron_a" style="background: #CCCEEE;"></div>
            <div class="chevron_b" style="background: #CCCEEE;"></div>
            <div class="chevron_o">
                <div class="chevron_m">
                    <div class="chevron_c">TEST</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: what do you mean by web resource?? you are saying other than static content if you load dynamic content the skew does not come?? is that what you mean?

Comment: Hi Alex. It's a web resource within Microsoft Dynamics CRM.

Comment: What version of IE are you using to test? What rollup is your CRM instance on? Where is CRM are you displaying this WebResource?

Comment: Btw, in my third question that was "in" not "is" - SO won't let me edit because I didn't click Save on my edit within the 5 minute window!

Comment: IE 11 & IE 9. Rollup 11. the web resource is displayed via an iframe in the incident/case form. I'm going to try it in an instance with rollup 16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, It looks like I have found the answer...

Rollup 11 doesn't support CSS3 (i think). With Rollup 11 installed the following meta tag forces IE9+ into IE8 mode and thus ignores the transform skew style.

```
<META http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=8>
```

Rollup 16 doesn't have this meta tag and the transform skew works fine in IE9+. I'm guessing this came as part of the cross browser compatability released with rollup 12???

Answer (score 0):

Have you loaded your CSS as a separate web resource and referenced it from within your HTML?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309536.aspx

Comment: I haven't no. Although I don't see how it would make any difference I'm willing to try anything! I'll try it now.

Comment: UPDATE: As expected that had no impact :-(

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to be OK.

Adding `CSS` to the `html Page` in head Section will work fine.

Two more thing: Where are you using the Webrescource ??

1. If you are using the web-resource on IFRame then make sure the JQuery library is added to
   the form.
2. Copy paste the URL of ur Web-Resource in the Internet Explorer and check in the developer tools.  `Your CSS, Divs, Jquery` are working fine no error are being thrown in the console.